# center alignment ANTD calendar design

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

how to align the date of the antd calendar to the center alignment in the calendar display? 
[image]

Comment: what do you want aligned ? Is it the text 'You have selected.......' ??

Comment: i want to align the date(29, 30,31,1,2...) to center like the days(su, Mo, Tu...). thanks @Dane

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do it is to add a CSS style override, by finding out which class to override. In this case, add a CSS file with following rule to override:

```
.ant-fullcalendar-value,
.ant-fullcalendar-fullscreen {
  text-align: center !important;
}
```

In case you were wondering, I found the classes via inspecting.
There is also a [`dataCellRender` prop](https://ant.design/components/calendar/#components-calendar-demo-notice-calendar) for the `<Calendar>` component, in case you need to format the output in each cell, or add content ( but the date remains there ). Hope this helps!